# How to reload systemd service?

Tags: docker, ubuntu, systemd

I have the following service defined

```
[Unit]
Description=Docker Compose Application Service [monitor]
Requires=docker.service
After=docker.service

[Service]
Type=oneshot
RemainAfterExit=yes
WorkingDirectory=/home/eugenekim/Documents/monitor/node-master
ExecStart=/usr/local/bin/docker-compose -f docker-compose.log.yml up -d es-log-00
ExecStop=/usr/local/bin/docker-compose -f docker-compose.log.yml down
TimeoutStartSec=0

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

The docker-compose.log.yml file has been changed and even the *.service file changed but system insists running the old definition somehow..

I've tried to run `daemon-reload` but it has no effect.
when I try to run

```
sudo systemctl reload docker-log                                                                                                                                                              14469ms
Failed to reload docker-log.service: Job type reload is not applicable for unit docker-log.service.
See system logs and 'systemctl status docker-log.service' for details.
```

It also does not have any effect..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're missing [`ExecReload`](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.service.html#ExecReload=).

```
[Unit]
Description=Docker Compose Application Service [monitor]
Requires=docker.service
After=docker.service

[Service]
Type=oneshot
RemainAfterExit=yes
WorkingDirectory=/home/eugenekim/Documents/monitor/node-master
ExecStart=/usr/local/bin/docker-compose -f docker-compose.log.yml up -d es-log-00
# docker compose will watch for changes
ExecReload=/usr/local/bin/docker-compose -f docker-compose.log.yml up -d es-log-00
# or you want a force restart
#ExecReload=/usr/local/bin/docker-compose -f docker-compose.log.yml restart es-log-00
ExecStop=/usr/local/bin/docker-compose -f docker-compose.log.yml down
TimeoutStartSec=0

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```